# Why is Bubble Sort in C# slower than JavaScript for me?

Tags: javascript, c#, sorting, bubble-sort

I am new to C# and have been playing around with it. I implemented a bubble sort in C# expecting it to be faster than JavaScript since it is a compiled language, but I am getting much slower speeds.

I am sorting 100,000 numbers.

In C# I am getting a speed of approximately: 1 minute and 30 seconds

C# Code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {

        List<int> randoms = generateRandoms(0, 1000000, 100000);
        Console.WriteLine(randoms.Count);

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        
        stopWatch.Start();
        bubbleSort(randoms);
        stopWatch.Stop();
        TimeSpan timeSpan = stopWatch.Elapsed;
        Console.WriteLine("Total processing time... {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:000}", timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes, timeSpan.Seconds, timeSpan.Milliseconds);
        Console.Read();
    }

    static List<int> generateRandoms(int min, int max, int amount) {

        Random rnd = new Random();
        List<int> randoms = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            int r = rnd.Next(min, max+1);
            randoms.Add(r);
        }

        return randoms;
    }


    static List<int> bubbleSort(List<int> list) {
        //Bubble sort
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < list.Count - i - 1; j++) {
                if (list[j] > list[j+1]) {
                    int temp = list[j];
                    list[j] = list[j+1];
                    list[j+1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        return list;
    }


    static void print(List<int> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

In JavaScript I am getting approximately: 30 seconds

JavaScript Code:

```
function bubbleSort(array) {

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < array.length-i-1; j++) {

            if (array[j] > array[j+1]) {
                [array[j], array[j+1]] = [array[j+1], array[j]];
            }
        }
    }
}

function generateRandoms(min, max, n) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1) + min));
    }

    return arr;
}

const array = generateRandoms(0, 1000000, 100000);
console.log(array.length);

const start = new Date();
bubbleSort(array);
const end = new Date();

console.log(`Performance: ${end - start}ms`);
```

I figured it had to do with the "List" data structure in C#, but after looking into the documentation, it appears all operations I am using in the bubbleSort function are O(1)

Does anyone have an idea why the speeds are much worse in C# for me?
I am using .Net v6.0.201. I am also using VSCode for both programs.

Comment: Significantly faster if you use an array...

Comment: Why would you expect it to be significantly faster? CLR Lists are dynamic arrays under the hood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# is as fast if not a little faster than JS when building in *release* mode. At least on my computer.

`Total processing time... 00:01:00.611` : debug bin

`Total processing time... 00:00:19.586` : release bin

Comment: So it appears not running in release mode was the problem. That solved the problem of poor performance. It is now running slightly faster than the JS program, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I figured it had to do with the "List" data structure in C#, but after looking into the documentation, it appears all operations I am using in the bubbleSort function are O(1)

O(1) isn't necessarily *fast*, it's just constant. Changing the C# code to use an array roughly doubles its speed. Not certain exactly why that is (List uses arrays under the hood) but IIRC arrays are sometimes able to elide bounds checks.

Also, your C# swap is doing a bit more work than your JS swap; you can replace this:

```cs
int temp = list[j];
list[j] = list[j+1];
list[j+1] = temp;
```

with this:

```cs
(list[j], list[j+1]) = (list[j+1], list[j]);
```

The two languages are closer after those changes, but JS still wins; I'm not certain why.

Update: C# is faster for me if I remember to compile in Release mode.

Comment: How are you defining "more work"? https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTAbgIYBO6AVugLzoAGANyMmRNpwAefdADsApgHd0AS1kAXANowAuiKRji1SZq46ANOhNcwcHfX7HTti1dP39TAL7IvQA===

Comment: When I ran the code, using the tuple approach was consistently a bit faster. I assumed it was due to skipping the temp variable and doing something more efficient, but I haven't looked into the exact IL/asm generated to see why.

Comment: I wondered about it, but the only thing I had to test with was c#fiddle which can do about 40,000 numbers in the ten second execution timeout and I was finding the tuple approach a bit slower (but it was a limited number of test runs and they weren't interleaved so perhaps it was a "at swap time X demand on fiddle's servers was light, at tuple time Y demand was higher"

Comment: I found an interesting article. The thing that stood out was the speed of array population in JavaScript versus C#. Perhaps this is the cause? https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-fast-is-javascript-to-c-or-c-29d104f4f255

Comment: @KyleC Are you running the C# code in release mode (`dotnet run --configuration Release` or `dotnet build --configuration Release`)? I forgot to do that initially and it makes a huge difference (.NET gets faster than JS).

Comment: @ReillyWood I was unaware of release mode. That makes sense. It drastically increased performance. The C# Program is now running a few seconds faster on average.